# setting column value to first row value in all subsequent rows based on condition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Please answer below, thanks for help in advance:
I would like to do below in spark, scala.

For dataset having two columns:`id, fn`; I want to set first id value same in all rows untill fn has non-zero value. Once row with fn having non-zero value is found, the next row "id" column will be used to fill in subsequent rows till again row with "fn" column having non-zero value.
And i want this updated "id" to be put in new column, to compare original "id" and new id value from this.

```
Example dataset:
val s1 = Seq(
     | (1, 0),
     | (1, 0),
     | (2, 0),
     | (2, 0),
     | (3, 4)
     | (5, 0),
     | (6, 0),
     | (7, 0),
     | (7, 8)
     | ).toDF("id", "fn")
```

The output dataset should be as follows:
New column added at extreme right.

```
Seq(
     | (1, 0, 1),
     | (1, 0, 1),
     | (2, 0, 1),
     | (2, 0, 1),
     | (3, 4, 1)
     | (5, 0, 5),
     | (6, 0, 5),
     | (7, 0, 5),
     | (7, 8, 5)
     | )
```

Comment: what if you have `val s1 = Seq( | (1, 0), | (1, 0), | (2, 0), | (2, 0), | (3, 4) |(4,4) | (5,1) | (5, 0), | (6, 0), | (7, 0), | (7, 8) | ).toDF("id", "fn")`?

Comment: the output in this case will be: Seq( | (1, 0, 1), | (1, 0, 1), | (2, 0, 1), | (2, 0, 1), | (3, 4, 1) |(4,4, 4) | (5,1, 5) | (5, 0, 5), | (6, 0, 5), | (7, 0, 5), | (7, 8, 5) | )

Comment: No, id column just takes the value the one after the row containing non-null "fd" value.. suppose in case of below input: Seq((1,0),(2,0),(3,4),(10,0),(11,0),(12,20),(30,0),(30,40)), the output is as: Seq((1,0,1),(2,0,1),(3,4,1),(10,0,10),(11,0,10),(12,20,10),(30,0,30),(30,40,30))

Comment: I just want to see the output for input `Seq((30,21),(1,0),(2,0),(3,4),(10,0),(11,0),(100,34),(12,20),(30,0),(30,40))`

Comment: output will be for that input is: Seq(30,21,30),(1,0,1),(2,0,1),(3,4,1),(10,0,10),(11,0,10),(100,34,10),(12,20,12),(30,0,30),(30,40,30)

Comment: the requirement you have won't be good to process in a cluster using apache spark. it should be faster with simple scala code using a loop.